# Replicate broken pipe error with tcp socket

Tags: c++, c, tcp, server, pipe

I have a a tcp server.
This is the code

https://pastebin.com/paesU39X

I had the following error during debugging:

```
Thread 10 "testserver" received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
[Switching to Thread 0x7f71feeec0 (LWP 5475)]
0x0000007fb6f13f70 in __libc_send (sockfd=50, buffer=0x7f71fee1e0, len=0,    flags=0)
at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/generic/send.c:27
27  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/generic/send.c: No such file or directory.
```

How can I replicate the broken pipe error to test a solution?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You may use kill to send specific signal to a process, e.g.:

```
kill -s PIPE 3363
```

The other solution is to create a client that will exit early i.e. it will close socket before your call to send.